# Django framework

Tags: django, django-database

I m trying to get the email of the person who just login.

if request.method == "POST":

```
    username = request.POST.get('username')

    password = request.POST.get('password')

    email = request.POST.get('email')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what your question is.  What errors are you encountering?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the emai of the logged in user than:
in **views.py** file:

```
user_email = request.user.email
```

in template file:

```
{{ request.user.email }}
```